# Line/border with border-radius, overflow:hidden and colored background

Tags: html, css

Please look at this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fmhhg00d/3/

```
<div><span>•</span></div>

div {
 width: 500px;
 height:500px;
 background: blue;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius:50%; /* --> Remove this and it's alright */
}

span {
 line-height:0.20;
 font-size: 2500px;
 color: white;
}
```

[See the problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3xmx.png)

In short, is there a reason why Chrome/Edge/Firefox all leave a small blue border when I use overflow:hidden and border-radius on the parent? Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: For me, the white dot is way smaller than on your picture, it doesn't intersect with the edges of the rounded div at all.

Comment: I think @Harry found a fix for this, which I tried to find.... did you Harry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is caused by anti-alias compositing. The `span` is drawn and anti-aliased separately from the `div` and then they are layered. The partial transparency around the edge of the `div` bleeds through the partial transparency around the edge of the `span`. There isn't really a way to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

That is, as *Ouroborus* answered, an anti-alias issue.

As a workaround, you could use pseudo elements to achieve the given layout

```css
body {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height:500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius:50%;
}
div::before,
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: -180px;
  width: 500px;
  height:500px;
  background: blue;
}
div::after {
  left: 140px;
  background: white;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: How can we cover this blue circle with white color from the bottom right corner to achieve a design like this - http://geometrydaily.tumblr.com/image/126507813677?lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_messaging%3B7rF1ABk9SqSL%2FjI1aqgpKw%3D%3D   I tried to do that but unable to cover bottom right corner without having that blue border line on covering with white. See this - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MQMrPw

Comment: @gauravparmar Like this you mean? ... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQeroB

Comment: @gauravparmar It is the anti-alias effect that cause that color bleed. Another option, which likely is the best, would be to use an SVG image instead. With that you can create a shape with transparent backgrounds as well, which will be a lot more difficult using HTML/CSS.